# Hibernate mapping for one-to-one

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping

I have two classes binded mapped with Hibernate and I can't figure out the configuration to map a **Drug** entry to my **PrescribedDrug** class.

```
public class PrescribedDrug implements Serializable {

    protected int prescribedDrugId;
    private int drugId;
    protected String sig;
    protected int quantity;
    protected int refillNumber;
    protected Drug drugInfo;
    ...
}

public class Drug implements Serializable {
    protected int drugId;
    protected String name;
    protected double strength;
    protected String strengthUnits;
    ...
}
```

My data model looks like this:

```
prescribed_drug             drug
----------                  --------------
prescribed_drug_id*         drug_id*
drug_id*                    name
sig                         ....
...
```

Here is my hibernate configuration:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="org.example.smartgwt.shared.model.PrescribedDrug" table="prescribed_drug" lazy="false">

        <id name="prescribedDrugId" column="prescribed_drug_id">
            <generator class="assigned"/>
        </id>

        <property name="drugId">
            <column name="drug_id"/>
        </property>
        <property name="sig">
            <column name="sig"/>
        </property>
        <property name="quantity">
            <column name="quantity"/>
        </property>
        <property name="refillNumber">
            <column name="refill_number"/>
        </property>

        <one-to-one name="drugInfo" class="org.example.smartgwt.shared.model.Drug" lazy="false" />

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="org.example.smartgwt.shared.model.PrescribedDrug" table="prescribed_drug" lazy="false">

        <id name="drugId" column="drug_id">
            <generator class="assigned"/>
        </id>

        <property name="name">
            <column name="name"/>
        </property>
        <property name="strength">
            <column name="strength"/>
        </property>
        <property name="strengthUnits">
            <column name="strength_units"/>
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**NOTE** here that I tried to map my **Drug** in the **PrescribedDrug.hbm.xml** config using a **one-to-one** but hibernate keeps telling me to add the fields of **Drug** to the **PrescribedDrug** file...

> field [name] not found on org.example.smartgwt.shared.model.PrescribedDrug

Entries in **drug** table are a static and contains the properties of the prescribed drugs.

Thank you.

Comment: What I don't get is this `private int drugId;` in the `PrescribedDrug` class.

Comment: Should not be there... I added it because of Hibernate. But I removed it in my final version. I had a few mistakes in my mapping, fixed thanks to @hvgotcodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

worked out answer in the comments, evidently....

Comment: Yeah, it wasn't there at the beginning, than Hibernate told me to add it. So I did. Than it told me to add "name" which is another field in the Drug class.

Comment: How else can Hibernate know that to which drug_id I'm relating the prescription?

Comment: @code-gijoe you can use a unique many-to-one, as layed out here....

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-onetoone

Comment: Actually 1 prescribed drug has a single drug id. But a drug can be related to multiple prescriptions.

Comment: @code-gijoe, if you use a one-to-one, the keys of the two classes have to be the same.  I think your situation is more appropriate for a constrained many to one.

Comment: @code-gijoe, are PrescribedDrug instances prescriptions?  If so, you might want a one-to-many from drug to prescription.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Saved me from going home to late on a friday night.

Found a couple of bugs in the .hbm.xml file for Drug (class name was wrong...) and also changed the mapping to drug table as so:
<many-to-one name="drugInfo" class="org.example.smartgwt.shared.model.Drug" column="drug_id" unique="true"/>

Answer (score 1):

In your mappings, I saw you only mapped for PrescribedDrug.

Change your 2nd mapping file class to Drug

```
<class name="org.example.smartgwt.shared.model.Drug" table="drug" lazy="false">
```